# Error: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager, clientscriptmanager

I got this Error when I added ScriptManager on a "Site.Master" (Master Page)

All child webForm of site.Master that contains ScriptManager. produce this error.....

Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a ScriptManagerProxy on your child pages/user controls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it also produce error     The control with ID 'ScriptManagerProxy1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

Comment: also, check your script manager on the master page is above your content placeholders

Comment: I Solve it already, the script manager of masterpage must be on top thank

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another instance of  in one of the pages /user controls that inherits from this master page.

Comment: I use updatepanel to content page. and the update panel need scriptmanager